# General form of a $4\times 4$ unitary matrix

Tags: matrices, unitary-matrices

I was trying to find the most general way of writing a $4\times 4$ unitary matrix but I got stuck when I obtained a set of equations that did not look very pretty after starting from something like:
$$U=
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c & d\\
e & f & g & h\\
i & j & k & l\\
m & n & o & p\\
\end{pmatrix}.$$

I was wondering if there was any clever way to write down such a matrix using a minimal amount of variables, probably under the form of exponentials and cosines/sines. Example of what I am looking for:

$$U=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
{e}^{+i\varphi} & {e}^{+i\varphi} & 0 & 0\\
{e}^{-i\varphi} & -{e}^{-i\varphi} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & {e}^{+i\psi} & {e}^{+i\psi}\\
0 & 0 & {e}^{-i\psi} & -{e}^{-i\psi}\\
\end{pmatrix},$$

but without any $0$ unless it is required due to the unitarity of the matrix. I have not found anything on the internet related to this topic, except these threads:

- [What is the general expression for a unitary 3x3 matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2328646)
- [The form of an N $\times$ N unitary matrix.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4204561)

I was hoping for either a systematic method to deal with $n\times n$ unitary matrices or a specific method to the $4 \times 4$ case.

Answer (score 2):

The columns of your matrix form an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb C^4$.
You can use the Gram-Schmidt procedure to start with four linearly independent column vectors $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ and produce an orthonormal basis:

$$ \eqalign{u_1 &= x_1/\|x_1\|\cr
            u_2 &= (x_2 -  u_1 u_1^* x_2)/\|(x_2 -  u_1 u_1^* x_2)\|\cr
            u_3 &= (x_3 - u_1 u_1^* x_3 - u_2 u_2^* x_3)/\| (x_3 - u_1 u_1^* x_3 - u_2 u_2^* x_3)\|\cr
            u_4 &= (x_4 - u_1 u_1^* x_4 - u_2 u_2^* x_4 - u_3 u_3^* x_4)/\|x_4 - u_1 u_1^* x_4 - u_2 u_2^* x_4 - u_3 u_3^* x_4\|\cr}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I understand the idea but I do not see how it solves my problem because I did not get how we choose the vectors $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4}$. Even for the case $n=2$, I could start with $x_{1}=(1,1)$ and $x_{2}=(-1,1)$. I think that would work but it would not be the most general form which is proposed as $x_{1}=(a,b)$ and $x_{2}=(-e^{i\phi}b^{*},e^{i\phi}a^{*})$ on the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix

Comment: The $x_1$ are arbitrary, as long as they are linearly independent.  Of course this isn't a parametrization, because the map from $(x_1, ]ldots, x_4)$ to $(u_1, \ldots, u_4)$ is not one-to-one.  You can (almost) make a parametrization by taking $x_1$, the first $3$ elements of $x_2$, and the first $2$ elements of $x_3$, all with norm $1$.  The other elements are then chosen (if possible) to make the vectors orthogonal, then the vectors are normalized.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** You could perhaps attempt to write $U$ as a product of matrices having the form $M_k = (I - 2 c_k c_k^*)$ where $c_k$ is a unitary column vector which $k$ first coordinates may be non-zero.

More specifically, you could choose $c_d$ by requiring that $M_d U e_d = e_d$ in dimension $d$, etc, where $e_d$ is the $d$-th basis vector.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you elaborate on why you choose to use this method? The form of your matrix $M_{k}$ looks similar to the Gram-Schmidt procedure proposed in Robert Israel's answer but I do not know if they are actually related or totally different methods. I could already find linearly independent vectors by looking at the wikipedia page on quaternions and 4D rotations but it seems to work only for real vectors...

Comment: Is it related to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation ?